# C# -- Is this checking necessary " obj is Person && obj != null"

Tags: c#

I saw the following code,

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  // From the book http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-2010-NET-4-0-Platform/dp/1430225491
  // Page 254!
  if (obj is Person && obj != null)
...
}
```

Based on my understanding, I think the code should be rewritten as follows:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (obj is Person)
...
}
```

Is that correct?

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

*An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.*

I think the extra checking for null is NOT necessary at all. In other words, that code "obj != null" should never be hit at all.

Thank you

// Updated //

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Employee
    {
        public static void CheckIsEmployee(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Employee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this is an employee");
            }
            else if (obj == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this is null");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("this is Not an employee");
            }
        }   
    }

    class NotEmployee
    { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();

            Employee.CheckIsEmployee(e);

            Employee f = null;
            Employee.CheckIsEmployee(f);

            NotEmployee g = new NotEmployee();
            Employee.CheckIsEmployee(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Output results:

```
this is an employee
this is null
this is Not an employee
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My preference would be to use the `as` keyword.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var objectToCompare = obj as Person;
    if ( objectToCompare == null )
        return false;
    ...
}
```

The advantage is that later in the method, you have a typed instance (objectToCompare) with which to do your comparisons.

You are correct in your assessment that `obj is Person` will return false if obj is not derived from Person or if obj is null and thus `obj is Person && obj != null` is redundant; you only need `obj is Person` if you are using that style. Technically, there might be a fractional performance gain by checking for null first, but the gain would be negligible.

Comment: Depends on what the definition of `is` is ;-)  In the case of .NET, `as` internally performs an `is` and sets the result to `null` if `is` is false.  jlew's solution is more optimal if `null` might sometimes be expected.

Comment: @Eric J :D. The reason for using `as` is primarily to have use of the typed instance later. So, in `jlew`'s solution, you would (presumably) need to cast `obj` as a `Person` after you determined it wasn't null so that you could do the rest of the Equals evaluation. Saves a line or two of code for the same result.

Answer (score 8):

Functionally it is correct, but it is quicker to check for null than to do a runtime type check, so you're better off checking for null first in most situations. That way, if obj *is* null, the overhead of the runtime type check will not be incurred.

Comment: @q0987, Well, I just did a quick performance test and it turns out to be essentially the same performance either way. Either operation can be performed hundreds of millions of times per second, so it's probably not worth worrying about from the performance standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Your version looks more correct to me. It won't be a Person unless it's non-null, so the obj != null is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

A reference to a Person can still be a null reference, so technically yes, both checks are required.

I like Thomas' answer as to how to handle both checks at once. `null as MyClass == null`, and `myClassInstance as OtherClass == null`, so with one check of the safely-cast object you've confirmed both conditions, and as he said, you have a strongly-typed reference to work with from then on.

There is an interesting discussion of the difference at low levels between `is` and `as` keyword operations. Google "Is as is or is is as" (I'm having Internet trouble at present). It turns out they work very similarly at the IL level.

Comment: +1 For getting me to look up "Is as is or is is as". http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments